# AWS VPC Routing to CIDR not part of VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have two VPCs setup, one in Sydney and another Oregon.

From my datacenter I have a VPN connection into the Sydney VPC.

A routing rule exists in my Sydney VPC to route all traffic to the Oregon subnet via a VPN instance.

Between the Sydney and Oregon VPCs I have an IPSEC connection which is working correctly. (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5472675506466066).

I am now trying to route traffic to the subnet in Oregon via the Sydney VPC from the datacenter. The virtual private gateway is unable to route the traffic from the VPN connection to the subnet in Oregon.

Is there any way to get the virtual private gateway to route traffic to a subnet that is not part of the target VPC CIDR?

Comment: Did you try BGP?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of VPG is to provide a link between IPsec commercial routers and a VPC, so clients can easily deploy hybrid cloud datacenters. It is not intended to work with VPGs in other VPCs.

Amazon as recently launched [VPC peering](http://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/new-vpc-peering-for-the-amazon-virtual-private-cloud/) for VPCs in the same region, so I think that multi-region VPC peering will be supported in the future.

In the mean time, the best way (IMHO) to provide a safe network link between VPCs is to deploy VPN instances in both VPCs,link them using standard VPN software (OpenVPN, L2TP/IPsec...), and then modify your route tables to redirect traffic through these instances.